# tableau Show the top 3 products for each of the top 5 vendors

Tags: group-by, tableau-api

I'm not sure how to go about this in tableau.

Using something similar to the superstore dataset, I want to make a table of the top 5 vendors (lets say by sales) and the top 3 products for each vendor (by sales for example).

The table might look like this

```
(Vendor, Product, Sales)
(Target, Ice Cream, 1000)
(Target, Spoon, 500)
(Target, Whipped Cream, 200)
(Walmart, Chair, 800)
(Walmart, Cereal, 400)
```

...

How can I do this in tableau?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of INDEX() and RANK() functions in Tableau

Read here: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/HowTo/finding-the-top-n-within-a-category?_ga=2.191851370.1706705908.1660100088-182821433.1653648634

[image: Refer this Technique]

https://youtu.be/z0R9OsDl-10

Comment: In case you need my professional help, reach out here: https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~0101d08ab532ab676c